# reference on backbone updating views, always based on state-change or as eventhandler side-effect?

Tags: backbone.js

Pretty cryptic question I admit.

I'm looking for references / best practice in updating views based on a GUI event. 
Basically I'm seeing 2 different ways to do this:

1. every view-change is a reaction to a model-change

   1. Gui event
   2. viewhandler (custom or 2-way binding lib) that

      - updates Model based on view
   3. the View has a `listenTo` defined on the MOdel that was updated, which gets invoked
   4. do whatever DOM-changes we want
2. Do DOM-changes directly in the viewhandler

   1. Gui event
   2. viewhandler (custom or 2-way binding lib) that

      - updates Model based on view
      - do whatever DOM-changes we want
   3. the View has a `listenTo` defined on the MOdel that was updated, which gets invoked

The fist approach seems the most clean to me: it can use validation rules on the model, before changing the DOM and the flow just feels better. However, I can't find any good references to back this up. What is generally considered best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know what is Overall Internet Agreement on that topic, but working on a fairly large Backbone application with complex views, the first approach is what has proven the most maintainable.

One way to see it is that as you know, Backbone's Views and Backbone's Routers are kinda sharing the workload of what would be an actual Controller in a standard MVC (say, Rails). What that means is that in a view, you'll typically have the logic to translate GUI events (click on X) to Model Change (do Y) and the logic to translate Model Changes (new state after Y) into DOM changes. That doesn't mean the logic needs to be in the same place, those are two separate things. Your model may be shared among multiple views and you need your View to react regardless of where the change is originating. You could also be waiting for the server to answer whatever, and so, the DOM update would be in a callback anyway.

A pattern I have been using a lot lately is to have a _renderUpdating() to update the DOM to let the user know that his action has been taking into account (add a spinner near to whatever triggered the change), but I let events do the actual re-rendering once the server has returned the new model.

There is nothing that prevents you from going with the 2nd approach in simple cases, but as your application grow, you'll be very happy to have more than just a single render() that erases everything (including subviews) and you'll be looking at having a clean break between view -> model (which is the role of a controller) and model -> view to allow for more flexibility.